# filting elements with 2 select list

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have li list each one has data-name and data-body
i want to show the only li's which match the selected value
first select is to select the car name 
second select is to select the car body

```
<ul id="shop">
    <li><a href="#" data-name="audi" data-body="cedan"><img src="images/1.jpg">audi-cedan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-name="bmw" data-body="cedan"><img src="images/1.jpg">bmw-cedan</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-name="audi" data-body="suv"><img src="images/1.jpg">audi-suv</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-name="bmw" data-body="suv"><img src="images/1.jpg">bmw-suv</a></li>
</ul>
<select id="select-name">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="audi">audi</option>
    <option value="bmw">bmw</option>
</select>
<select id="select-body">
    <option value="">select</option>
    <option value="cedan">cedan</option>
    <option value="suv">suv</option>
</select>
```

here is what i tried , when i select first one its working but when i select the second one with it it not working fine

```
$('#select-name').change(function() {
    $("li a").hide();
    var selected = $('#select-name option:selected').attr("value");
    $("li a").each(function() {
        if ( $(this).attr("data-name") === selected ){
            $(this).show()
        }
    }); 
});

$('#select-body').change(function() {
    $("li a").hide();
    var selected = $('#select-body option:selected').attr("value");
    $("li a").each(function() {
        if ( $(this).attr("data-body") === selected ){
            $(this).show()
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we need to do is take into account both `selects` as I presume `Audi SUV` should only show if audi and suv are chosen?

Have a look at this:

```
// look at selects when they change
$('select').change(function() {
    var selectedName = $('#select-name option:selected').val();
    var selectedBody = $('#select-body option:selected').val();
    if(!selectedName && !selectedBody){ // nothing selected - reset and get out
        $("li").show();
      return false;
    }
    $("li").hide();
    $("li a").each(function() {
        // no name, just find body
        if(!selectedName){
            $("li a").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("data-body") === selectedBody ? $(this).parent().show() : '';
            })
          // no body just find name
          } else if(!selectedBody){
            $("li a").each(function() {
            $(this).attr("data-name") === selectedName ? $(this).parent().show() : '';
            })
          // else match and find both
          } else if ( (selectedName && $(this).attr("data-name") === selectedName) 
                    && (selectedBody && $(this).attr("data-body") === selectedBody )){
            $(this).parent().show()
        }
    }); 
});
```

[Here's a fiddle to see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/studiotime/2h186rdk/3/)

Comment: Yes this solved the issue , can you please tell me how to show all result when the user select the defualt value?

Comment: Check updated code and fiddle - works for any combination now

Answer (score 0):

when you say it is not working, I'm assuming that mean that if user has selected "audi" in the first select, then chooses "suv" in the second, you expect the display to be "audi suv", but currently displays "audi suv" and "bmw suv". 
If this is the case, you'd need to change your functions to beware of other selections. for example:

```
$('#select-body').change(function() {
    $("li a").hide();
      var selectedName = $('#select-name option:selected').attr("value");
    var selected = $('#select-body option:selected').attr("value");
    $("li a").each(function() {
        if ( $(this).attr("data-body") == selected && $(this).attr("data-name") ==selectedName){
            $(this).show()
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I could improve the code from Christoph's answer below:

```
$('#select-body').change(function() {
    var selected = $('#select-body option:selected').attr("value");
    $("li a[data-body='" + selected + "']").hide(); 
});
```

...but this code will show all links if the user selects the first option (with blank value). So it could be better to inverse the logic just to show want you want:

```
$('#select-body').change(function() {
    var selected = $('#select-body option:selected').attr("value");
    $("li a").hide();         
    $("li a[data-body='" + selected + "']").show(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So, now I got what you want:

I've used the same logic for both dropdowns, because I assume you want to filter by the both:

```
$('#select-name, #select-body').change(function() {
  var selectedName = $('#select-name option:selected').attr("value");
  var criteriaName = selectedName !== "" ? "[data-name='" + selectedName + "']" : "";
  var selectedBody = $('#select-body option:selected').attr("value");
  var criteriaBody = selectedBody !== "" ? "[data-body='" + selectedBody + "']" : "";
  $("li a").hide();
  $("li a"+criteriaName+criteriaBody).show();
});
```

Look the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/TXFtJRHTxGZo3QwQ8uNY

Comment: I would improve this by passing the logic to <li> tag so it's more cleaner